# Editable fields in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, plist, field

I am building app, that there will be a "Admin Panel" Where features can be turned on and off. I have come to realize that i am not sure how that is gonna work. Would I create a Db and make that editable or would i need to make a plist and have the options work from there? Some of the options that will be able to be turned on and off will range from pages, to certain parts of the page. Anyone have any suggestion or somewhere to point me in a direction to get this answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you decide to persist the data is up to you. You might try [NSUSerDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Regardless of how you store the data, you can use an editable UITableView with a cell style of  [UITableViewCellStyleValue1](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UITableViewCellStyleValue1). This is similar to how many of the settings are handled in the Settings app.

> `UITableViewCellStyleValue1`
>
> A style for a cell with a label on the left side of the cell with
>   left-aligned and black text; on the right side is a label that has
>   smaller blue text and is right-aligned. The Settings application uses
>   cells in this style.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very broad and the answer might be "it depends". A typical approach would be to leverage `NSUserDefaults` and store the preferences there.
Read the [documentation on NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and consult the [Preferences and Settings Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i) for a bigger picture.

Answer (score 0):

I did this recently and decided against using the database for storage of these options as it seemed unnecessarily complex for just storing a few settings.  OTOH, I opted not to use the plist.  In the end, I decided to use the NSKeyedArchiver to save those settings out to a file in the filesystem.  My decision against the plist was based on the fact that I had a couple of complex data structures I wanted to save.

It may be that it could have been done in a plist or using NSDefaults, but the save and load methods took only a few lines of code, then I created a class containing all of the items I needed to save.

Were I doing it again I think I would do it the same way.